# Using Columns in one table to populate column of naother table

Tags: join, reference, sharing

I have an excel file (Alpha.xlxs) with one column (A) called CountryList. This column lists a subset of data I pulled from a database. 128 countries are listed.

I have another excel file (Beta.xlxs) with two columns (A) and (B). These are called "Country List" and "Region List". This file lists all the countries in the world along with their associated region (ie: Africa, Asia, etc.)

I want to create a "Region List" column in Alpha.xlxs that lists the regions of the 128 countries I have listed. I do not know how to go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that using VLOOKUP. You just need to copy the data from Beta.xlxs to Alpha.xlxs

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you give me any additional detail into how to do that?

Comment: simple googling gives you tutorial like this https://www.timeatlas.com/vlookup-tutorial/